# How to throw errors from a setter in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, database, data-structures, error-handling

I wanted to know if there was a way to have setters throw errors in Swift. I assume this would solve my problem but the fact that I couldn't find a way to do it makes me wonder if I've structured my code the right way. Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:

I have a struct called `Account` which users can edit from their end

```
struct Account {
    var strikes: Int = 0
    
    private var _monetizationLevel: Int = 1
    
    var monetizationLevel: Int {
        get { _monetizationLevel }
        set {
            guard strikes == 0 else { print("Please resolve copyright strike before adjusting moentization level"); return }
            guard newValue <= _monetizationLevel else { print("Monetization level can only be increased by a server admin"); return }
            _monetizationLevel = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Using Swift's inbuilt support for setters felt like a natural way to go about editing characteristics of your account. eg. `myAccount.name = "newName123"`, `myAccount.monetizationLevel -= 4` (or whatever)

However, since `monetizationLevel` has certain restrictions on how much of it you can edit I **assumed** throwing errors would be a fitting solution to it (since simply printing warnings felts very weak). Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a way to have the setter throw an error. I thought about using throwing functions like `setMonetizationLevel(to: Int)` but using function setters seemed really silly considering Swift has inbuilt ones specifically to eliminate the awkwardness of using function setters. I would prefer a Swift-y solution that preserves the naturalness of `myAccount.name = "blah"`, `myAccount.monetizationLevel -= 5`, etc. just for consistency sake.

On the other hand, if there's no way to achieve this without using function setters what would be a better way to restructure my `Account` struct? How would you guys go about this?

Comment: It doesn’t work and even if it did it wouldn’t be as swifty as you suggest since you would need to use `try` and maybe also surround the assignment with a do/catch. It can also be problematic if a get or set contains to much logic in my opinion so my suggestion would be to use a function instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson True. Using "try" isn't ideal but like I said I assumed error-handling would be the most fitting solution to figure out why the "set" failed. Do you have any recommendations to how I could restructure my code?

Comment: See my edited comment.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ah that's unfortunate that I'll have to use a function. I'll try brainstorming a way to restructure my code through cuz I'm reluctant to have a setter function just for this property. The inconsistency would really bother me :/ Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: The contract of a setter is simple - it sets a property. You need a more complicated contract - the operation can fail/throw. This means that you need a function.  It may be that this business logic doesn't belong in `Account` - maybe it belongs somewhere else. For example, where do you guard against setting `strikes` to `-1`?  Perhaps you shouldn't be using setters at all?  Maybe there should be functions `recordStrike()` which increments the number of strikes and `clearStike()`/`clearAllStrikes()` which decrement/zero the count. `stikes` would then be a `private (set)` property

Answer (score 2):

This has already been discussed in comments, no setters cannot `throw` - the contract of a setter is simple - the property value is set. There is no way for the compiler to know that  `account.monetizationLevel` can `throw`.

What you need to consider is where you want to implement you business logic. It looks like you are trying to implement business logic in this struct, and you say "The inconsistency (of mixing setters and functions) would really bother me :/"

If you are going to implement business logic in this struct, then you probably shouldn't use setters at all.  Presumably there is some business logic around `strikes` - ie they should be >=0

Maybe recording a strike should also reduce monetisation?

Also, your logic says that only admins can increase monetisation, but there is no way for the setter to know if the caller is an admin - you can provide this to a function.

Exposing properties as read-only and using functions for setting is possibly a better approach. I think it results in an API that is easier to understand and which separates operations from implementation.

For example:

```
enum AccountException: Error {
    case BadCopyrightStanding
    case NotPermitted
}

struct Account {
    private (set) var strikes: Int
    private (set) var monetizationLevel: Int
    var hasStrikes: Bool {
       return strikes != 0
    }
    mutating func recordStrike() {
        self.strikes+=1
        self.monetizationLevel = 1
    }
    
    mutating func clearStrike() {
        self.strikes = max(self.strikes-1,0)
    }
    
    mutating func clearStrikes() {
        self.strikes = 0
    }
    
    mutating func setMonitizationLevel(_ level:Int, isAdmin: Bool) throws {
        guard self.strikes == 0 else {
            throw AccountException.BadCopyrightStanding
        }
        guard isAdmin || level <= self.monitizationLevel else {
            throw AccountException.NotPermitted
        }

        self.monetizationLevel = level
    }
}
```

Or, if you are implementing business logic elsewhere, then this should just be a "dumb struct" and it should not enforce the relationship between strikes and monetisation.